# How to see constant values in .a lib files?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, libraries

I declared a constant using define statement in my C file.

```
#define COMPRESSION_VERSION 1.0.0
```

Now I have created `libcompression.a` library which includes the above C file. Now I need to check my defined constant value in the library using terminal.

Comment: You can try `strings libcompression.a | grep COMPRESSION_VERSION`

Comment: Better try with `strings libcompression.a | grep 1.0.0` since C preprocessor has replaced all occurences of COMPRESSION_VERSION with 1.0.0.

Comment: @StefanR im not able to get any result ..any reasons

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with this amount of information... Maybe you should check all string with `strings libcompression.a | less`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define COMPRESSION_VERSION 1.0.0
```

is a C pre-processor directive, which isn’t expected to survive macro expansion, let alone compilation.

If you want a symbol that appears in your library, you need to add it explicitly; for example

```
static const char * COMPRESSION_VERSION = "1.0.0";
```

This will then appear in your library:

```
$ nm -A libcompression.a
libcompression.a:compression.o:0000000000000000 d COMPRESSION_VERSION
```

and you can see its value using `objdump -s`.

A common technique is to embed the version in the symbol; *e.g.* for OpenSSL:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1|grep OPENSSL_1
0000000000000000 A OPENSSL_1_1_0
0000000000000000 A OPENSSL_1_1_0d
```

Comment: Your sentence "*... is a C pre-processor directive, which isn’t expected to survive macro expansion, let alone compilation*" should be true in most cases, but what about `gcc -g3`: "*Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions present in the program. Some debuggers support macro expansion when you use -g3*"?

Comment: @Philippos yes, with `-g3` the macro definition is available in the library, until it’s stripped of course. That’s not something I would encourage readers to rely on (except in their own builds). In particular, the information wouldn’t be available in packaged versions of the library.